# Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.FileNotFoundException(Apache Hive 1.2.1)

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop

My issue is related with Hive UDF,
I have created one UDF which convert String date to julian date , It's working fine when I execute select query but it throws an error while using command  Create table temp as.

```
Create function convertToJulian as 'com.convertToJulian'
Using jar 'hdfs:/user/hive/'.
```

Execute Select Query :

```
SELECT name, date FROM  custTable
WHERE   name is not null  and convertToJulian(date) < convertToJulia
(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())));
```

OutPut :

```
converting to local hdfs:/user/hive/udf.jar
Added [/usr/local/hivetmp/amit.pathak/9381feb3-6c5f-469b-b6b1-
 9af55abbdabd/udf.jar] to class path
Added resources: [hdfs:/user/hive/udf.jar]
```

It's working fine and providing me exact data what I need. 
Now in second step I want to add this data in another new table so I added

```
CREATE Table trop
As
SELECT name, date FROM  custTable
WHERE   name is not null  and convertToJulian(date) < 
convertToJulian (to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())));
```

Output :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/local/hivetmp/amit.pathak/9381feb3-6c5f-469b-b6b1-9af55abbdabd/udf.jar
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
```

I am not able to find out why its fetching data from hdfs location 
 hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/local/hivetmp/amit.pathak/9381feb3-6c5f-469b-b6b1-9af55abbdabd/udf.jar

I also tried several ways like adding data manually in hdfs.
But hive generating random session id which create folder name with same session Id name.

Comment: Does it work as a temporary function? And is `com` really your package and `convertToJulian` your class name? As an aside, the reason for the JAR being renamed is Hive jobs run on multiple nodes and so Hive copies the JAR to each node. This in in keeping with the Hadoop principle of "move the code to the data". I believe that temporary folder is destroyed immediately after the job finishes, but I've never had a reason to go digging for it and I doubt your problem requires it either.

Comment: No it's not working as temporary function, yes com is package name and convertToJulian is class name.  usr/local/hivetmp/amit.pathak/9381feb3-6c5f-469b-b6b1-9af55abbdabd   - "usr/local/hivetmp/amit.pathak/9381feb3-6c5f-469b-b6b1-9af55abbdabd" is get created with all new session and I can see my jar file exist in this file system ,  yes you are right it should write on multiple nodes, but it's not happening as in hadoop file system I can see folder get created but  but jar is absent.

Comment: So `add jar 'hdfs:/user/hive/udf.jar';
    create temporary function convertToJulian as 'com.convertToJulian';` produces the same error? I'm always explicit with the full JAR path rather than just its root directory.

Comment: I have tried   as you suggest                                                                         add jar 'hdfs:/user/hive/udf.jar';                                                                   create temporary function convertToJulian as 'com.ConvertToJulian';            but still facing the same issue as mention above.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help any more. Just for a different approach you could try loading the JAR from a local location, but that shouldn't change anything - the bug relating to that was fixed in 2010.

Comment: thanks Ben , if I found anything will share

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94361/discussion-between-amit-and-ben-watson).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am able to fix above issue , now I have two ways to fix this, I have added my finding on my blog, you can refer this link [Hive udf exception Fix](http://techtalkgig.blogspot.in/2015/12/hive-errors.html)